# When does argparse not complain about this missing argument?

Tags: python, argparse

There is probably an obvious answer to this question, but I've looked at it for a bit without figuring it out. This is some old Python code using argparse. I haven't used argparse recently, so I may have forgotten some nuance.

```
#test.py

def load_crossval_dataset(args):
    schema, samplenum, permuted, search = args.schema, args.samplenum, args.permuted, args.search

    print "schema", schema
    print "samplenum", samplenum
    print "permuted", permuted
    print "search", search

import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

# create the parser for the "crossval" command                                                                                                                 
parser_crossval = subparsers.add_parser('crossval', formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
parser_crossval.add_argument('schema', help='name of schema')
parser_crossval.add_argument("-n", "--samplenum", action="store", type=int, dest="samplenum", help="number of samples to do crossvalidation on")
parser_crossval.add_argument("-p", "--permuted", action="store_true", dest="permuted", help="permuted dataset", default=False)
parser_crossval.add_argument("-s", "--search", action="store_true", dest="search", help="model search", default=False)
parser_crossval.set_defaults(func=load_crossval_dataset)

args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)
```

Let us invoke this as:

```
python test.py

usage: test.py [-h] {crossval} ...
test.py: error: too few arguments
```

Now as

```
python test.py crossval -h

usage: test.py crossval [-h] [-n SAMPLENUM] [-p] [-s] schema

positional arguments:
  schema                name of schema

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -n SAMPLENUM, --samplenum SAMPLENUM
                        number of samples to do crossvalidation on (default: None)
  -p, --permuted        permuted dataset (default: False)
  -s, --search          model search (default: False)
```

Now as

```
python test.py crossval -n 1 -s True                                                                                                                         

schema True
samplenum 1
permuted False
search True
```

Question: why does argparse not complain about the missing `schema` argument, and why does it set it to `True`?

Comment: I bet the values of the `args` will be different.  `search` is a boolean `True`, `schema` is a string `'True'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a glance, the `-s` option is boolean - so its presence implies True and it requires no argument. So when you say `python test.py crossval -n 1 -s True`, the `True` gets parsed as being the schema argument since the `-s` switch doesn't require a value.

This much can in fact be gleaned from the usage string in the help text:

```
usage: test.py crossval [-h] [-n SAMPLENUM] [-p] [-s] schema
```

The `[-s]` indicates that it's a nullary option, unlike `-n` which is listed as `[-n SAMPLENUM]` since it requires an argument (`SAMPLENUM`).

**Edit**:

This behavior is stated in the [Python 2.7 Documentation for argparse](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html), which I infer is the version you are using in your example since you are using the statement- rather than function-form of `print`.  To quote section 15.4.3.2:

> 'store_true' and 'store_false' - These are special cases of 'store_const' using for storing the values True and False respectively. In addition, they create default values of False and True respectively.

Comment: Yes, that's the correct answer. I guess my memory of how this works had become fuzzy. Is "its presence implies True and it requires no argument" mentioned in the docs, and if so, can you point it out (quote it) to me? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @minuteman3. However, this does not document the fac that the presence of the flag `-s` etc. is equivalent to setting the value to `True`, which was the piece which is missing, in my opinion.

Comment: Maybe I'm just used to the behaviour and so biased in my reading of the text. You're right that the argparse documentation could really stand to be improved. Personally I prefer to use https://github.com/docopt/docopt these days.

Answer (score 1):

The option `-s` doesn't take an argument (`store_const`, `store_true` and `store_false` actions don't take an argument — this could stand to be clarified in the documentation). So in `python test.py crossval -n 1 -s True`, the argument `True` is a positional argument of `crossval`, not an argument of `-s`; thus it's the value of `schema`.

`python test.py crossval -n 1 -s` correctly complains about the missing argument to `test.py crossval`.

Comment: Yes, having looked through https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html, I don't see any place where it is stated that a boolean option implies True by its presence and False by its absence. While this is natural, and presumably the reader is supposed to infer it, it would be nice if it was stated explicitly.

Comment: From the docs: `'store_true' and 'store_false' - These store the values True and False respectively. These are special cases of 'store_const'`.  There are also a number of examples using `store_true`.

Comment: `argparse` builds on the legacy of `optparse`, which describes its `store_true` action at: https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#handling-boolean-flag-options

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, but beware that [they aren't fully compatible](http://bugs.python.org/issue9334).